# Creating function Trim-to(symbol list) in LISP

Tags: lisp

trim-to (symbol list)
Write a function named trim-to that takes a symbol and list as parameters. Return a new list
starting from the first occurrence of the input symbol in the input list. If there is no
occurrence of the symbol, return nil.
For example:
(trim-to ‘c ‘(a b c d e))
This should return the following list:
‘(c d e)

Not quite sure how to start here. If someone could walk me through the steps they take to construct this function I would be forever grateful!

Comment: Further, I know I need to use cons to construct a new list beginning with the first occurrence of the symbol I am trying to find. If not directly answering this question, could someone show me a similarly constructed function as a basis to explain what is going on to search for a symbol? It's only my second day using lisp and I am struggling to transform my imperative/OOP skills to Lisp.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Recursion-with-list.html)

Comment: @dratenik I think I've seen example before and understand basic recursion (the last problem was a factorial and I had no issue with it). I guess it's more understanding what exactly is going on here. I found the code for this problem online and am trying to break it apart to see what's going on, 
 (defun trim-to(sym list)
                   (cond ((null list) nil)
                         ((equal sym(car list)) list)
                         (t (trim-to sym (cdr list)))
                         )
                   )
I guess my question is, what's happening on the line returning true?

Comment: `(defun trim-to (item list) (member item list))`? Just kidding. PLease show what you have tried so far. Without code in the question there will be just text answers.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lisp/lisp_cond_construct.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have a symbol and a list:

- if the list is the empty list you have failed;
- if the first element of the list is the symbol this is the list you want;
- otherwise take the rest of the list – now you have a symbol and a list ...